# Having two different features using .show() and .hide() without conflicting eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, filter, show-hide

Please see here: http://jsfiddle.net/mAMY2/1/

As you can see, there is a filter feature as well as a "show more" feature. I'd like to change the way the "show more" feature functions to avoid conflict with the filter function. For example, maybe there is an alternative to .show() and .hide()?

Summary of the conflict:

> The "Show More" function and "Filter" function both work by
>   manipulating the display value. If, for example, only three out of
>   nine boxes are showing and you choose to filter a specific category,
>   more than three boxes could potentially be displayed. Similarly, if you choose to only > display a specific category, but then wish to show more, the other category will also be ?> displayed.

Thank you

Comment: can you be more clear  ?

Comment: `$('.filter-cat1 a').click(function(){
        $('.cat2').hide();
        $('.cat1').show();
    });

 $('.filter-cat2 a').click(function(){
        $('.cat1').hide();
        $('.cat2').show();
    });

 $('.all a').click(function(){
        $('.box').show();
    });` http://jsfiddle.net/mAMY2/1/

Comment: an alternative to .show() is .attr("style", "'display:inline;'") and an alternative to .hide() is .attr("style", "'display:none;'")

Comment: I don't know how I can be more clearer than showing the code? I summarized the conflict and it is blatantly clear when engaging the features on the jsfiddle. Please let me know what is unclear, thank you

Comment: I think your not so simple use of vocabulary and grammar is complicating what should be a simple question, remember this forum is international

Comment: sorry, hopefully it is clear when interacting with the jsfiddle

Comment: I think the problem is that when you filter with any category and click on show more it will display the other boxes too, yes?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `.addClass` and `.removeClass` and then control visibility with css.

Comment: That is a great idea, I will try it now

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly, when you click show More you are expecting the same category box which is selected that only should display not all then you can use this, i dont think its a good way coz if the category increases so does the if condition.But atleast you get an idea

```
var cat=0;
$('#showMore a').click(function(){
    if(cat==0)
     $('.box:hidden:lt(3)').animate({height: 'toggle'}, 500);
    if(cat==1)
     $('.box cat1:hidden:lt(3)').animate({height: 'toggle'}, 500);
    if(cat==2)
     $('.box cat2:hidden:lt(3)').animate({height: 'toggle'}, 500);
});
```